# Xamarin forms Prism Content Page Design

Tags: xamarin, navigation, prism

I'm working on Xamarin Project and I don't need navigation bur, I switched it off but now I cant move app content of page
[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:imgExt="clr-namespace:GulfStar.Xamarin.Extensions"
             x:Class="GulfStar.Xamarin.Views.StatusPickerPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">


    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" >
            <Image Source="{imgExt:ImageResource GulfStar.Xamarin.Images.Icon.png}" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70"/>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,17,0,0" FontSize="Title">GSI Accountability</Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I figured out who it happen
[image]

How to remove blue section

Comment: what does "can't move app content of page" mean?

Comment: I mean move content to the top

Comment: if you want it at the top why do you have `VerticalOptions="Center"`?

Comment: It's still not moving

Answer (score 0):

Use  `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`  to hide the navigation bar.

Comment: Did you put it on the second page? Because I successfully removed the navigation bar at the top with this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make that thing disappears
when you navigation to some page does not use Navigation page NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/StatusPickerPage");
Use
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("StatusPickerPage");
And it would not track navigation and its not needed if you have only two pages

Comment: Why would one navigate to `NavigationPage/...` in the first place if he doesn't want a navigation page?